# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in Ant Script for WsImport

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, wsimport

I am trying to use WSImport2 to create some bean classes from wsdl files. But I get the errors

```
H:\Workspace\common-build.xml:745: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.<init>(BGMBuilder.java:147)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:117)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:425)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:277)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:112)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2268)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:168)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:111)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:414)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:175)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:153)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImportBase.runInVm(WsImportBase.java:569)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsTask2.execute(WsTask2.java:457)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImportBase.execute(WsImportBase.java:552)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.execute(WsImport2.java:23)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:306)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:225)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindingComponent.getClassSelector(BindingComponent.java:65)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ColorBinder.<init>(ColorBinder.java:62)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindGreen.<init>(BindGreen.java:63)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.nav.NavigatorImpl.getBaseClass(NavigatorImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.nav.NavigatorImpl.getBaseClass(NavigatorImpl.java:59)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core.Adapter.<init>(Adapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CAdapter.<init>(CAdapter.java:82)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.TypeUseFactory.adapt(TypeUseFactory.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CBuiltinLeafInfo.makeAdapted(CBuiltinLeafInfo.java:192)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CBuiltinLeafInfo.<clinit>(CBuiltinLeafInfo.java:387)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.SimpleTypeBuilder.<clinit>(SimpleTypeBuilder.java:897)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.DefaultClassBinder.<init>(DefaultClassBinder.java:98)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ClassSelector.<init>(ClassSelector.java:214)
        ... 59 more

Total time: 11 seconds
```

There are a lot more lines in the stack trace. If needed I will upload it. I have most of the JAX jars in my classpath.

The line causing the problem, is:

```
<wsimport wsdl="${build.dir}/src/${wsdl.file}" destdir="build" wsdlLocation="file:/WEB-INF/wsdl/${wsdl.file}" failonerror="true" verbose="true">
        <depends dir="${build.dir}/src" includes="*.xsd" /> 
        <produces dir="${lib.dir}" includes="${webservice.name}${webservice.component}WSBeans.jar"/>
    </wsimport>
```

I am having issues uploading the whole stack trace, but I am only filling this section up to make the question post!

Comment: InvocationTargetException is like a wrapper: The line indicated in the strack trace is executing some code dynamically, and that code threw an exception. In other words, the interesting trace is the one you did not paste.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Oh, give me a minute, I will update the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a mismatch in the JAXB XJC jar version. It mismatched with the JAXB Impl and Core jars.

The two jars were:

```
jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar
```

While my XJC was:

```
jaxb-xjc-2.2.7
```

Upgraded it to the same version and now it works fine.